# Execution of Oracle Procedure prior to Source Qualifier that must use the same Oracle session

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a security procedure that has to be called just before a select from source table. Without this procedure no rows are returned.

The problem is that I have checked several ways to call this procedure just before Source Qualifier:

- Pre-sql into the `Source Qualifier` As a Stored procedure
- Pre-load source
- Put several sql sentences in the sql query propertie in `Source Qualifier` (added 2014-11-08)

Always seems that Powercenter opens a new oracle connection, where security procedure takes no effect.

What could be the correct way to put both process together and use the same Oracle session?

Note added 2014-11-08:

I have tried also to put 2 sentences in the SQL Query of the Source Qualifier:

```
call procedure('param'); 
SELECT field1, field2, field.... from VI_ETL...;
```

[image]

and I get error ORA-24333 Zero Interaction Count, perharps because first item is not a SELECT statement that returns rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SQL Query` on `Source Qualifier` to invoke a series of statements - the security Stored Procedure being the first one.

Comment: I have already tried some sort of this in the SQL Query: "call procedure('param'); SELECT field1, field2, field.... from VI_ETL...; and get error ORA-24333 Zero Interaction Count

Comment: I don't have an Oracle instance to test it, but how about creating a wrapping SP that will call the safety SP first and the Select right after? Same thing you put in SQ - but via one more SP.

Comment: There is a DB2 solution https://community.informatica.com/message/61244 but it is not allowed to Oracle. informática cannot deal with SYS_REFCURSOR object. I have found the workaround of inserting a temp table inside procedure and read from this source in the Sq.